# Subgroups of $S_4$ which are not parabolic subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

Let $(W, S)$ be a Coxeter system. The standard parabolic subgroups of $W$ are the subgroups $W_J = \langle J \rangle$ generated by subsets $J$ of $S$, and the parabolic subgroups of $W$ are the $W$-conjugates of the standard parabolic subgroups.

In particular, in type $A$, $W$ is the symmetric group.

Let $S_4$ be the symmetric group on $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Are there some subgroup of $S_4$ which is not a parabolic subgroup? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Look, any parabolic subgroup of $W$ is generated by reflections. Take a subgroup generated by a rotation and you are done. For example, in $S_4$ take the subgroup generated by $s_1s_2=(123)$.

In fact, you could take the set of rotations in $W$. For $S_4$ this is $A_4$ and in general this is $W_{even}=\{w\in W\mid \det w=1\}$.